# How to read a .sql file and add contents to combobox?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a `.sql` file (table schema) and I want to read the file and add each line (each line being a field) to a combobox. I tried googling it, but can't find anything on reading SQL files, not sure if it's different from a text file.

An example schema:

CREATE TABLE test_table(

name varchar(75),

phone varchar(9),

email varchar(75))

I want to gather email field (name, phone, email) and add them to a combobox drop down list.

Comment: Do you want to parse sql file rather than load it into a database and then query it?

Comment: It _sounds_ like you just want to read each line like you would a text file.  Perhaps you could post a sample file that could be used to better understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you want to read the file and it is a *.sql* file, it is not any different than reading any other text file. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I edited with a schema example, does that make it a little more clearer?

Answer (score 1):

To do it properly, you need to parse SQL file like a program code (which it is). Take a look at [this](http://www.andriescu.nl/sql/sql-how-to-parse-microsoft-transact-sql-statements-in-c_sharp_view_column_binding/) for example, or look for some other SQL parser library. Warning: parsing arbitrary SQL won't be a trivial task, as SQL has somewhat arbitrary syntax.

If your SQL files have very well-defined structure (e.g., they are auto-generated), you can try using regular expressions to parse them, even if it usually ends up in an unreadable and fragile code.